# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I got this error: "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): 
android.app.Activity#onCreateView" whenever I'm extending my class with FragmentActivity.

Isn't FragmentActivity compatible with API 8? and if not, is there away to make it compatible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem, including where you are referencing `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for replying. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Alahlavo Can you post you Activity and the error log.I think it's because some line is wrong in OnCreateView.

Comment: @tinysunlight Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: What's the error log? You can edit your quesition.

Comment: @tinysunlight The only error shown, is the one on the title - "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView FragmentActivity"

Comment: @Alahlavo you need to extend form the support library version of `FragmentActivity(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)` Check your imports to see whether you are using this. Or you can use `AppCompactActivity` as well

Comment: @dishan FragmentActivity is already imported that way. I tried AppCompactActivity, and it does the same thing (same error).

Comment: @Alahlavo You can use FragmentActivity but you can't override onCreateView.

Comment: @tinysunlight I don't understand, I don't have any method named oncreateview, but only onCreate

Comment: You can read the error log. Some method you use  trigger onCreateView.

Comment: @tinysunlight That's embarrassing, I just had to clean my project as it seems. I'm sorry for wasting your time. and thanks for all your replies gentleman.

Comment: @Alahlavo It's really embarrassing!

Answer (score 0):

Switch the class you're importing from the regular one to the one on the support library, The regular fragment and fragementActivity are only avialbe from android 3.0 (hence API 11) and that is the cause for the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you mean v7? If that's what you mean, It's already imported.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

in build.gradle.

android.app.Activity#onCreateView is added on API 11.

You can set minSdkVersion to 11 or just don't use this method.

Comment: Oh,my fault.Maybe you just need go to build.gradle  and change minSdkVersin to  11.